# How to import sparkdl in zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, databricks

I'm trying to add the sparkdl (spark-deep-learning) jar but Zeppelin give error

```
ImportError: No module named 'sparkdl'
```

I trying using :

```
spark-deep-learning-0.1.0-spark2.1-s_2.11.jar
```

also tried 0.2.0 version of sparkdl

used maven coordinates as below

```
databricks:spark-deep-learning:0.2.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
```

and also tried using the path of the jar independency

python version 3.5
spark version  2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually tricky and there is actually two problems here.

From one hand and for some reason, `pyspark` isn't able to load the jar correctly when using the following command :

```
--jars spark-deep-learning-*.jar
```

thus `zeppelin` can't do anything about it. But it works well when you add the following options to `pyspark`:

```
--packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:0.2.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
```

On the other hand, `zeppelin` doesn't seem to be able to fetch the package from the `bintray repo` but that yields an error when you start/restart your interpreter in the UI.

To solve this, you'll need to add/modify the following line in `conf/zeppelin-env.sh` and restart `zeppelin`:

```
SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS="--packages databricks:spark-deep-learning:0.2.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"
```

That will load the package into zeppelin using spark and not zeppelin :

[image]

**PS:** This solution will not work for zeppelin <0.7

Comment: thnk you, i put jar path in spark.default and its working but i have new error ImportError: No module named sparkdl.image.imageIO

Comment: I really advise you to follow my solution using the `SPARK_SUBMIT_OPTIONS`

Comment: please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47036106/importerror-no-module-named-sparkdl-image-imageio

Comment: I believe it's in the same issue actually. Zeppelin isn't capable of copying sparkdl on the executors...