# ImportError: No module named sparkdl.image.imageIO

Tags: image, apache-spark, jar, deep-learning, apache-zeppelin

i'm doing image classification using spark.
i have already imported sparkdl jar(added path of jar in the conf/spark.default)

```
ImportError: No module named sparkdl.image.imageIO
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:797)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 161, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 91, in read_udfs
    _, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 78, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 54, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 169, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/home/ubuntu/install/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 454, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj)
ImportError: No module named sparkdl.image.imageIO
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
```

`from sparkd import readImages`
when i read image it work good ,
but when create model and fit the image DataFrame that time it gives 
No module named sparkdl.image.imageIO